# From fetch request to DOM: How to convert the response into a walkable DOM structure?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument

Example:

1. Fetch call that gets a HTML document as response.
2. Response gets interpreted as DOM structure.
3. One can now use `querySelector` to search for specific elements in that structure.

My idea so far (probably way more complex than it should be):

```js
const responseString = await(await fetch('https://.....')).text();
const element = document.createElement('html');
element.innerHTML = responseString;
```

There has to be a standard for this right?

Something like: `const responseString = await(await fetch('https://.....')).domNodes();`

Comment: I don't see a problem with your current approach. HTML string to DOM is a pretty standard `.innerHTML` use case.

Comment: @ggorlen - Well, in theory the code above tries to create an invalid HTML structure, because the text presumably has `<html>` at the beginning if not `<!doctype html><html>`, neither of which is valid as a child of an `html` element. [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) is the cleaner way to do it. But yeah, it would work. :-)

Comment: I see, good point. Can they use `.outerHTML` for the same effect?